# testing mobile in rspec integration test but cant set session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, rspec, integration-testing, session-cookies

I'm writing an integration test for mobile pages.  I've got the mobile system set up like is descriped in the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices).  Basically a session is set up if the devise is mobile, and my controller sends to a desktop home page if it's not mobile, but to a mobile home page if it is mobile.  Rspec does not support sessions, so I don't know how to make the integration file know that it's supposed to go to the mobile home page.

methods defined in a helper to detect if mobile.

```
  def check_for_mobile
    session[:mobile_override] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  end

  def mobile_device?
    if session[:mobile_override]
      session[:mobile_override] == "1"
    else
      (request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/) && (request.user_agent !~ /iPad/)
    end
  end
```

controller action

```
  def home
    check_for_mobile
    if mobile_device?
      @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:company]
      render "pages/home_mobile"
    elsif company_signed_in?
      redirect_to companies_home_path
    else
      @request = Request.new
      @request.company = params[:company]
      render 'pages/landing'
    end
  end
```

I basically need to get `mobile_device?` to return true in the request spec.  I could write a bunch of crappy code to get this to work but there must be a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `spec_helper.rb` (you may need the `rack_session_access` gem if it's not already included as a dependency) :

```
require "rack_session_access/capybara"
```

Add a before filter to describe or context block:

```
before(:each) do
  session[:mobile_override] = "1"
end
```